# Redirect User to Specific Page

Tags: redirect

I want to create or use a script that do this:

if a users click on the bit.ly link then it redirects to my website

to homepage.com/folder1

and if the user delete the string folder1, then he will go to homepage.com

but I want that the users even if he delete folder1 string and go to homepage.com, having cookies in his device,

even if the users redirect to homepage.com, I want that the user still go from homepage.com always to homepage.com/folder1

is that possible?

is that clear?

thank you for your support.

Comment: It's possible, but what do you mean by folder1? WordPress treats paths a bit differently. Do you have a WordPress site?

Answer (score 0):

As this is A WordPress Specific:

```
function my_page_template_redirect_cookie() {
    if( is_front_page() && isset($_COOKIE['the_cookie']) ){
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/folder1/' ) );
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect_cookie' );
```